# The named parameter 'inputDetailsFromUser' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm making an flutter app in visual studio code and it shows these errors [problems description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMuHY.png)

and this is the code for one of these problems :

[code of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUfvO.png)

Comment: Can you include more about your paymentMethod

Comment: You mean the code or the payment method itself?

Comment: You can include how you are getting `PayoutMethod` , If it is custom class, consider including the code-snippet

Comment: Please follow the question asking guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc"

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that your `PayoutMethod` class constructor does not have property named `inputDetailsFromUser`. Show us the definition of the `PayoutMethod` class and then we will be able to help you more.